# Hibernate query:Don't delete child when removing association with parent

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am removing a Child from its association(many to one) to Parent.When i use saveOrUpdate method on Parent, Hibernate by default tries to remove Child from the Table.Is it a bug with hibernate?? How can I avoid this condition???

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing looks like the behavior you'd get when cascading `delete-orphan` (or any equivalent using annotations). If you are and don't want this behavior, then don't cascade it. If you aren't, please post classes, mappings and a scenario allowing to reproduce.